# Combining categorical data of different columns into one column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = {'A': [None,A,None,None,A,None,None], 
      'B': [B,None,None,B,None,None,None],
      'C': [None,None,C,None,None,None,None]}
```

And I want to combine these three columns into one to have:

```
df =pd.DataFrame ({'Categories': ["B","A","C","B","A",None,None]})
```

I tried [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html), but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['categorical'] = df[df.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)),axis=1)
```